# Delete unwanted entry in Autocomplete in Microsoft Edge

Tags: autocomplete, microsoft-edge

How do you delete one unwanted entry in Autocomplete in Microsoft Edge?  This question has NOT been correctly answered yet.

Comment: Don't just post the same thing again, or it will just get closed. once you have sufficient reputation, you can post a bounty on a question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)